# Python - coordinates plotting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, ipython

i need advice. In my DB, i have x points and y points in form:

```
df = pd.read_sql_table('table', cnx)
```

| id | curves |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [(x,y),(x,y),(x,y) etc.] |
| 2 | [(x,y),(x,y),(x,y) etc.] |

```
type(df['curves']) #pandas.core.series.Series
```

And I would like to try to plot Line Graph.

I try several solutions. but nothing worked for me.

```
data = df['curves']
plt.plot(*zip(*data))
plt.show()
```

or

```
data_in_array = np.array(data)
transposed = data_in_array.T
x,y = transposed #but here i got error - not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode the curves list column

```
df = df.explode('curves').reset_index()
```

Create separate x and y columns

```
df['curves_x'] = df.curves.str[0]
df['curves_y'] = df.curves.str[1]
```

Plot using seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.lineplot(data=df, x='curves_x', y='curves_y', hue='id')
plt.show()
```

To understand better, let's take some sample data,

```
   id                          curves
0   1  [(10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 50)]
1   2  [(10, 10), (20, 40), (30, 20)]
```

Explode the column and reset the index

```
   id    curves
0   1  (10, 20)
1   1  (20, 30)
2   1  (30, 50)
3   2  (10, 10)
4   2  (20, 40)
5   2  (30, 20)
```

Create x and y columns

```
   id    curves  curves_x  curves_y
0   1  (10, 20)        10        20
0   1  (20, 30)        20        30
0   1  (30, 50)        30        50
1   2  (10, 10)        10        10
1   2  (20, 40)        20        40
1   2  (30, 20)        30        20
```

The plot will look like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, but  it doesn't work for me. When I view it, I have in column `curves_x`  : `[` and  in `curves_y` : `(`

Comment: Before all this, ensure your `curves` column is of list type and not a string. If it is a string (which seems to be the case),  use `testdf['curves'] = testdf['curves'].map(ast.literal_eval)` and `import ast` too @Cesc

Comment: when i do it i get an error: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._set_item(key, value)`

Comment: Use `df.loc[:, 'curves'] = df['curves'].map(ast.literal_eval)` @Cesc

Comment: still nothing - `ValueError: malformed node or string: [(0, 4.579), (0.2153549, 9.862635), (0.4196396, 9.862635), (0.6154251, 9.069808), (0.8132706, 22.54274), (1.012405, 20.9576), (1.210602, 21.57384), (1.409637, 23.24702), (1.61058, 21.92599), (1.80954, 25.53644), (2.008942, 24.9202), (2.20961, 22.63078), (2.410034, 25.36037), (2.609161, 22.63078), (2.80925, 23.33506), (2.929764, 24.48002), (3.129486, 29.58708), (3.328705, 32.22915), (3.529053, 37.3362), (3.729904, 33.28557), (3.928864, 30.82008), (4.128937, 28.79476), (4.330307, 26.50534)......]`

Comment: Something's wrong with your data. Please check. The code works on sample data.

Comment: is it possible that the problem may be that the coordinates are not integers but, for example, in the following ?: `[(0, 4.579), (0.2153549, 9.862635), (0.4196396...`

Comment: Decimal numbers are not an issue. You could try `ast.literal_eval('[(0, 4.579), (0.2153549, 9.862635)]')`. It will work! @Cesc

Comment: yes, you right.  It will show a red warning window, but the operation will be performed. Thank you